# Get a node with a prespecified namespace

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How would I get the following etree node, where I don't have to qualify every operation with the namespace? For example:

```
>>> c='''<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
             <sitemap><loc>http://www.vudu.com/sitemap-static.xml</loc></sitemap>
         </sitemapindex>'''
>>> node=etree.fromstring(c)
>>> node.xpath('//loc')
[]
```

How could I establish the `node` such that I can do `node.xpath(''/loc')` and get results?

Comment: How about register a *very short* prefix once, and use it to qualify the namespace : `node.xpath('//n:loc')`, is that acceptable?

Comment: From the LXML FAQ: http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-specify-a-default-namespace-for-xpath-expressions